# Cutting perfect 45° by hand

Tags: hand-tools, hand-saw

I am trying to cut wooden planks with a 45° to joint them together.

For this end I have made this jig for my handsaw.
[image]

All the angles measured are perfect. I cut very slowly to avoid to much play from saw. The piece of wood is fixated with clamps and doesn't move during the cut

It just doesn't work
[image]

I have also remade the whole thing. Put some magnets into the jig to make the saw cuts even more exact. Tried different pieces of wood. When using the jig for 90° degree cuts everything works perfect and i get dead square right angles.

Comment: Over the last 5 weeks or so, I'm sure you've learned that the StackExchange communities operate on a Question & Answer basis. Please [edit] to actually ask a question. Otherwise, you've just given us some facts...

Comment: Somehow I can not edit the question, my question is if there is a way to increase precision of the cut

Comment: I'm going to take the unusual step of explaining my downvote (the second one). It seems clear that you've done no prior research on cutting 45s, because you'd surely have come across the common approaches *which aren't this*. In addition you'd surely have come across the fact that, where accuracy is paramount, cutting results straight from the saw are never accepted. *Even 90° cuts are routinely perfected on a shooting board if absolute precision is required/desired.* And in addition to getting far more accurate length *and* angle you get a far superior surface which is v important for mitres.

Comment: Are you entirely sure that your square and protractor are 100% in agreement?

Comment: Any other tools at your disposal? Handsaw, circular saw? Jigsaws are not known for their accuracy in jigs because of blade wander. If it has to be a jigsaw, with practice and the right blade, you can cut spectacularly close to the line and then clean it up as noted below.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested general approach for handtools is not to expect perfection with the first step. For the specific need of a 45 degree angle you'd want a shooting board for a hand plane in a similar vein to your current jig.

An alternative to cutting accurate 45 degree angles when you want to have the finished joint at a 90 degrees is to make sure that the cut pieces result in a 90 degree angle but not worry about each of them individually being 45 degrees. So if you jig consistently produces a 43 degree angle, cut one piece that way and the other piece rotated 90 degree to have a complementing 47 degree angle.

Comment: This is an excellent concise Answer, however, the second paragraph relies on the cutting being accurate enough (and repeatably so) that one can take advantage of complementary angles. Given the problem outlined by the OP this doesn't seem likely here, and is anyway not something generally relied upon outside of machine work with its extreme repeatability.